# Cannot log in to the MySQL server (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-error-1045

I am having an issue with logging into phpMyAdmin, specifically when I log in with the root user and the correct password it gives me this error:

```
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

When I log in using the 'pma' user without password it works, but it doesn't have the permissions I need to use obviously. I'm pretty sure this is the 1045 error.

Here are my settings in config.inc.php:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'sutdenlol';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

If you need more information please tell me instead of down voting.

Edit: 
PHP scripts can access the server with root with the correct password.

Comment: just a quick bump

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

and check do you have installed MySql Server on your machine. You can download it here - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/